# Completion Handlers for Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I am currently rewriting a project from the Objective-C to Swift. Most of the project is done, but I am having problems translating a method that has a completion handler. I have reviewed the documentation, but I am still having problems. The method is:

```
- (void)start:(void ( ^ ) ( WTStartupConfiguration *configuration ))startupHandler 
completion:(void ( ^ ) ( BOOL isRunning , NSError *error ))completionHandler
```

In objective-C, I would simply write is as:

```
[self.architectView start:^(WTStartupConfiguration *configuration)
 { } completion:^(BOOL isRunning, NSError *error) {}}];
```

I cannot get a good grasp on closure syntax in Swift. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You want something like this for your function:**

```
func start(startupHandler:(configuration: WTStartupConfiguration)->(), completion:(isRunning:Bool, error:NSError?)->()) {

    let configuration = WTStartupConfiguration() // create your configuration

    startupHandler(configuration:configuration) // call your startup handler closure

    ... // do some stuff

    let isRunning = false // replace with actual logic
    let error = nil // replace with your actual error detection

    completion(isRunning: isRunning, error: error) // call completion closure
}
```

**You can then call it like this:**

```
start(
    { configuration in

        // do something with your configuration

    }, completion: {isRunning, error in

        // do something with your isRunning & error.

})
```

---

**Closures are defined with the syntax `(arguments) -> (returns)`**, where you replace `arguments` with your inputs and returns with your `outputs` (much like how a function is defined).

In your case, your closures don't return anything, so we define them like:

```
(isRunning:Bool, error:NSError?) -> ()
```

(where an empty tuple `()` is used to show that nothing is returned)

You then create them, and pass them into functions (if the argument types of the closure are known) using the short-hand notation of:

```
closureArgument: { (arguments here, without types as they're known) in

}
```

```
closureArgument: { isRunning, error in 

}
```

The more formal way of passing them into a function is:

```
closureArgument: { (arguments with types) -> (returns with types) in

}
```

```
closureArgument: { (isRunning:Bool, error:NSError?) -> () in 

}
```

You can then invoke the closure in pretty much the same way that you call functions.

```
closureArgument(isRunning: false, error: nil)
```

**I find [this site](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/) is great to refer to for closure syntax (and can probably explain it better than me).**

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure others will give you very detailed answers with example code, so I'll just mention this for future reference:

### How Do I Declare a Closure in Swift?

From [fuckingclosuresyntax.com](http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com) or the SFW version [goshdarnclosuresyntax.com](http://goshdarnclosuresyntax.com/).

> As a **variable**:
>
> ```
> var closureName: (ParameterTypes) -> (ReturnType)
> ```
>
> As an **optional variable**:
>
> ```
> var closureName: ((ParameterTypes) -> (ReturnType))?
> ```
>
> As a **type alias**:
>
> ```
> typealias ClosureType = (ParameterTypes) -> (ReturnType)
> ```
>
> As a **constant**:
>
> ```
> let closureName: ClosureType = { ... }
> ```
>
> As an **argument to a function call**:
>
> ```
> func({(ParameterTypes) -> (ReturnType) in statements})
> ```
>
> As a **function parameter**:
>
> ```
> array.sort({ (item1: Int, item2: Int) -> Bool in return item1 < item2 })
> ```
>
> As a **function parameter with implied types**:
>
> ```
> array.sort({ (item1, item2) -> Bool in return item1 < item2 })
> ```
>
> As a **function parameter with implied return type**:
>
> ```
> array.sort({ (item1, item2) in return item1 < item2 })
> ```
>
> As the **last function parameter**:
>
> ```
> array.sort { (item1, item2) in return item1 < item2 }
> ```
>
> As the last parameter, **using shorthand argument names**:
>
> ```
> array.sort { return $0 < $1 }
> ```
>
> As the last parameter, **with an implied return value**:
>
> ```
> array.sort { $0 < $1 }
> ```
>
> As the last parameter, **as a reference to an existing function**:
>
> ```
> array.sort(<)
> ```
>
> As a function parameter **with explicit capture semantics**:
>
> ```
> array.sort({ [unowned self] (item1: Int, item2: Int) -> Bool in return item1 < item2 })
> ```
>
> As a function parameter **with explicit capture semantics and inferred
>   parameters / return type**:
>
> ```
> array.sort({ [unowned self] in return item1 < item2 })
> ```
>
> *This site is not intended to be an exhaustive list of all possible uses of closures.*

Comment: I believe this below is not even correct!!!   As a function parameter:

array.sort({ (item1: Int, item2: Int) -> Bool in return item1 < item2 })

Answer (score 2):

For you to understand how the closure works, I have separated the definition of closures and not defining it inline to the method signature. You could do the following:

```
func start(startupHandler: (configuration: WTStartupConfiguration) -> Void, completion: (isRunning: Bool, error: NSError) -> Void ) {
    //Your code for start method
}

var startupHandlerClosure = { (configuration: WTStartupConfiguration) -> Void in
    //Your code for startupHandler closure
}

var completionClosure = { (isRunning: Bool, error: NSError) -> Void in
    //Your code for completion closure
}

//Method call
start(startupHandlerClosure, completion: completionClosure)
```

@originaluser2 beat me to it.. he provides example with additional code.